# Immer.js using undefined base object

Tags: typescript, immer.js

I'm trying to use `immer.js` to set a property in an object which is possible undefined - as are it's children. Can I ensure the object is initialized somehow?

```js
type Config = {
  personal?: {
    navigate?: boolean;
  }
};

const myFunc = (configuration?: Config): void => {
  const mergedConfig: Config = produce(configuration, (draft): void => {
    draft.personal.navigate = true;
  });
};
```

Using this code, I receive a typescript error saying `Object 'draft' is possibly 'undefined'`.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to that specific error, you can suppress it by adding the [non-null-assertion-operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to both `draft` and `personal` properties, resulting in:

```
draft!.personal!.navigate = true;
```

However, I think you should add more code to validate those possibly undefined/null properties, otherwise you will run into an error such as

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'personal' of undefined
```

or

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'navigate' of undefined
```

When using the *non-null-assertion-operator*, you as a developer are telling the compiler - "Yes, I'm sure this value is defined".